# count path data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and it has a column with path data. The data inside df['Path'] is some thing like following

```
/js/jquery.validate.js
/paidadsimages/arangaya.png
/images/sinhala-banner.jpg
/js/jquery.validate.js
```

I want to count unique paths sort and display. My expected output is something like following:

```
/js/jquery.validate.js 2
/paidadsimages/arangaya.png 1
/images/sinhala-banner.jpg 1
```

Can not figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df.groupby('Path').count().sort('Path', ascending=False)

                             Path
Path                             
/js/jquery.validate.js          2
/paidadsimages/arangaya.png     1
/images/sinhala-banner.jpg      1
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't feel this was such simple :(

Comment: Well, Pandas makes it seem simple because of all the goodness 'behind the scenes'. :)

Comment: Definitely! I used size() instead of count in your answer..:) Thanks!